# How to implement Edit Feature in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, edit

Below 2 links give the preview of my sample application.

http://img812.imageshack.us/i/image1adl.jpg/ : shows mine sample application. All fields are self explanatory (if query, let me know)

http://img834.imageshack.us/i/image2vc.jpg/ : shows, when clicked the "Edit" button from the grid, the timings are shown correctly but the order gets disturbed. (See 7:00 coming on the top and then the timings list are seen).

My Questions

1. How to correct the timings problem? (Link # 2)

Code for "Edit" is below

```
protected void lnkEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int imageid = Convert.ToInt16((sender as Button).CommandArgument);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection();
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConn"].ConnectionString;
    string sql = @"SELECT * FROM Images WHERE IsDeleted=0 and Imageid='"+ imageid +"'";

    SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlconn);
    sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlcommand.CommandText = sql;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand);
    da.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtImageName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
        chkIsActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["IsActive"].ToString());
        ddlStartTime.DataSource = ds;
        ddlStartTime.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["StartTime"].ColumnName.ToString();
        ddlStartTime.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ImageId"].ColumnName.ToString();
        ddlStartTime.DataBind();
        ddlEndTime.DataSource = ds;
        ddlEndTime.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["EndTime"].ColumnName.ToString();
        ddlEndTime.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ImageId"].ColumnName.ToString();
        ddlEndTime.DataBind();
        BindDropDownList();
        IsEdit = true;
    }
```

1. When i edit the existing record in the grid, i am getting the values, but the record is not being updated but added as a new record into db. I am aware that i am suppose to write update script. But where to write that?

Below the code is for the same;

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            string strImageName = txtImageName.Text.ToString();
            int IsActive = 1;
            if (chkIsActive.Checked)
                IsActive = 1;
            else
                IsActive = 0;

            string startDate = ddlStartTime.SelectedItem.Text;
            string endDate = ddlEndTime.SelectedItem.Text;

            if ( Convert.ToDateTime(endDate) - Convert.ToDateTime(startDate) > new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0) || Convert.ToDateTime(endDate)- Convert.ToDateTime(startDate) < new TimeSpan(2,0,0))
            {   
                //Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'> alert('Difference between Start Time and End Time is 2 hours'); </script> ");
                lblHours.Visible = true;
                lblHours.Text = "Difference between Start Time and End Time should be 2 hours";
                return;
            }

            if (checkConflictTime())
            {
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                lblMessage.Text = "Time Conflict";
                return;
            }

            //if (checkTimeBetween())
            //{
            //}

            if (fuFileUpload.PostedFile != null && fuFileUpload.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {
                lblHours.Visible = false;
                byte[] imageSize = new Byte[fuFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength];
                HttpPostedFile uploadedImage = fuFileUpload.PostedFile;
                uploadedImage.InputStream.Read(imageSize, 0, (int)fuFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength);

                SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection();
                sqlconn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestConn"].ConnectionString;

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                if (IsEdit == false)
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Images(FileName,FileContent,IsDeleted,IsActive,StartTime,EndTime) values (@img_name, @img_content,@IsDeleted,@IsActive,@StartTime,@EndTime)";
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "Update Images set FileName=@img_name, FileContent=@img_content, IsDeleted= @IsDeleted,IsActive= @IsActive, StartTime=@StartTime,EndTime=@EndTime";
                }
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = sqlconn;

                SqlParameter ImageName = new SqlParameter("@img_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                ImageName.Value = strImageName.ToString();
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ImageName);

                SqlParameter ActualImage = new SqlParameter("@img_content", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
                ActualImage.Value = imageSize;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(ActualImage);

                SqlParameter DeletedImage = new SqlParameter("@IsDeleted", SqlDbType.Bit);
                DeletedImage.Value = 0;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(DeletedImage);

                SqlParameter IsActiveCheck = new SqlParameter("@IsActive", SqlDbType.Bit);
                IsActiveCheck.Value = IsActive;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(IsActiveCheck);

                SqlParameter StartDate = new SqlParameter("@StartTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                StartDate.Value = startDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(StartDate);

                SqlParameter EndDate = new SqlParameter("@EndTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100);
                EndDate.Value = endDate;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(EndDate);

                sqlconn.Open();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconn.Close();

                if (result > 0)
                {
                    lblMessage.Visible = true;
                    lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded!";
                    gvImages.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblMessage.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Please help!

Comment: I would start with stepping through the code to see what the value of IsEdit comes out as. If it is not equal to False then you insert a record, which is the problem you described.

Comment: @Justin: thanks for input.
IsEdit is nothing but a bool variable, which when true should update the record. It is set to true when edit event is called (here in code snippet # 1 -> last line). My Problem: The condition is always coming to false.

Comment: Imagine, if the IsEdit condition comes true, and the compiler goes to update block, then would the rest of code written there in be ok? Won't the values be coming entered from user into update query?

Comment: @Xor power - I am not sure, that is why I suggested stepping through the code. Put a break point in using Visual Studio and check to make sure that the boolean value has the correct value. Truthfully I think you need to separate this into at least 2 questions, there is a lot going on here.

Comment: thanks Justin: I believe that the boolean is set to false intially, that's why the variable is set to false. seems weird though..

Comment: @justin: Say if the compiler goes to update query in if condition, then is the code written correct as far as update is concerned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you define `Bool/Bolean IsEdit`? I think its value is reset on page postback, that's why it is always **false** and the record is being inserted. I would suggest you to use a hidden field to track this and set its value there and check the value upon insert/updating. Finally it will be something like...

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
   //your code
   hiddenField.Value = "true"; // you can set default value to false
}
```

and then after

```
if (hiddenField.Value == "false")
   {
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Images(FileName,FileContent,IsDeleted,IsActive,StartTime,EndTime) values (@img_name, @img_content,@IsDeleted,@IsActive,@StartTime,@EndTime)";
   }
   else
   {
    cmd.CommandText = "Update Images set FileName=@img_name, FileContent=@img_content, IsDeleted= @IsDeleted,IsActive= @IsActive, StartTime=@StartTime,EndTime=@EndTime";
   }
```

Comment: @Akhtar: Yes!, i believe that could be because of postback.
one small question: would the rest of code be same when commandtext is set to update query?

Comment: yes, I don't think so, you need to change any thing in your existing code. It seems to be OK to me. Good Luck :)